# Visual Studio 2010 - How to change colors specific to code type?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm wondering if there is a way to change the colors for a specific code?  I'd like have a different color scheme for C# than I do for JS?

Another question is there an easy way to find out what the "display items:" name is within the Options > Enviroment > Fonts and Colors?  For many of the of the code items it's difficult to know exactly what MS is calling object types.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the code highlighting I would recommend:
http://studiostyl.es/

Comment: I appreciate the link but I already have my theme, which I actually got from that link.  I'm wanting to modify that theme specific to the code type.  I got this idea from another IDE I use for php which allows for changing color globally and by code type.